# xbuild in rpmbuild not working

Tags: mono, fedora, rpmbuild, xbuild

I'm currently trying to package our project into Fedora RPM. Therefore I use the following spec: http://sourceforge.net/p/audiocuesheet/code/145/tree/trunk/RPM%20Build/AudioCuesheetEditor.spec

If I try to build the rpm with xbuild inside the "build" - stage, the output is as follows:

```
+ xbuild /property:Configuration=Release AudioCuesheetEditor.sln
XBuild Engine Version 2.10.8.0
Mono, Version 2.10.8.0
Copyright (C) Marek Sieradzki 2005-2008, Novell 2008-2011.

Build started 01/01/2013 16:53:18.
__________________________________________________
Project "/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.sln" (default target(s)):
    Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
            Building solution configuration "Release|x86".
    Target Build:
            Project "/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.csproj" (default target(s)):
                    Target PrepareForBuild:
                            Configuration: Release Platform: x86
                            Created directory "bin/Release/"
                            Created directory "obj/x86/Release/"
                    Target CopyNonResxEmbeddedResources:
                            Copying file from '/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/gtk-gui/gui.stetic' to '/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/obj/x86/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.gtk-gui.gui.stetic'
                    Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
                    No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
                    Target CoreCompile:
                            Tool /usr/bin/gmcs execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug- /optimize- /out:obj/x86/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.exe /resource:obj/x86/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.gtk-gui.gui.stetic,gui.stetic gtk-gui/generated.cs MainWindow.cs gtk-gui/MainWindow.cs AssemblyInfo.cs Language.cs Speechfile.cs Option.cs Program.cs Optionfile.cs Cuesheet.cs Track.cs Cuesheetfile.cs Audiofile.cs TextInputfile.cs Projectfile.cs MainClass.cs Logfile.cs OptionWindow.cs gtk-gui/AudioCuesheetEditor.OptionWindow.cs /target:winexe /main:AudioCuesheetEditor.MainClass /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/Mono.Posix.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glib-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glade-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/atk-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Xml.dll /warn:4
gtk-gui/MainWindow.cs(152,51): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
gtk-gui/MainWindow.cs(171,52): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
gtk-gui/MainWindow.cs(199,53): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
gtk-gui/AudioCuesheetEditor.OptionWindow.cs(181,67): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
gtk-gui/AudioCuesheetEditor.OptionWindow.cs(247,64): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
                    Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
                    Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.csproj".-- FAILED
            Done building project "/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.csproj".-- FAILED
    Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "Build" in project "/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/AudioCuesheetEditor-0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.sln".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
```

The interessting thing is, if I use the standard source package and run the xbuild everthing works perfect:

```
[sven@Sven AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1]$ xbuild /property:Configuration=Release AudioCuesheetEditor.sln 
XBuild Engine Version 2.10.8.0
Mono, Version 2.10.8.0
Copyright (C) Marek Sieradzki 2005-2008, Novell 2008-2011.

Build started 01.01.2013 16:54:17.
__________________________________________________
Project "/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.sln" (default target(s)):
    Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
            Building solution configuration "Release|x86".
    Target Build:
            Project "/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.csproj" (default target(s)):
                    Target PrepareForBuild:
                            Configuration: Release Platform: x86
                            Created directory "bin/Release/"
                            Created directory "obj/x86/Release/"
                    Target CopyNonResxEmbeddedResources:
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/gtk-gui/gui.stetic' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/obj/x86/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.gtk-gui.gui.stetic'
                    Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
                    No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
                    Target CoreCompile:
                            Tool /usr/bin/gmcs execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug- /optimize- /out:obj/x86/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.exe /resource:obj/x86/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.gtk-gui.gui.stetic,gui.stetic gtk-gui/generated.cs MainWindow.cs gtk-gui/MainWindow.cs AssemblyInfo.cs Language.cs Speechfile.cs Option.cs Program.cs Optionfile.cs Cuesheet.cs Track.cs Cuesheetfile.cs Audiofile.cs TextInputfile.cs Projectfile.cs MainClass.cs Logfile.cs OptionWindow.cs gtk-gui/AudioCuesheetEditor.OptionWindow.cs /target:winexe /main:AudioCuesheetEditor.MainClass /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/Mono.Posix.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glib-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glade-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/atk-sharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Xml.dll /warn:4
                    Target _CopyDeployFilesToOutputDirectoryPreserveNewest:
                            Creating directory '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/Texts.xml' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/Texts.xml'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/LICENCE_DE.TXT' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/LICENCE_DE.TXT'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/LICENCE_EN.TXT' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/LICENCE_EN.TXT'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/LICENCE.TXT' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/LICENCE.TXT'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/README.TXT' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/README.TXT'
                            Creating directory '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-64.png' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-64.png'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-48.png' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-48.png'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-32.png' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-32.png'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-24.png' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-24.png'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-22.png' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-22.png'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-16.png' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-16.png'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-48.ico' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-48.ico'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-32.ico' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-32.ico'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-24.ico' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-24.ico'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-22.ico' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-22.ico'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-16.ico' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-16.ico'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/CHANGELOG.TXT' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/CHANGELOG.TXT'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/KNOWN_ISSUES.TXT' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/KNOWN_ISSUES.TXT'
                            Creating directory '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/samples'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/samples/Sample_Inputfile.txt' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/samples/Sample_Inputfile.txt'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/samples/Sample_Project.ace' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/samples/Sample_Project.ace'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/samples/Sample_Inputfile2.txt' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/samples/Sample_Inputfile2.txt'
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/resources/icons/application-x-cue-128.png' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/resources/icons/application-x-cue-128.png'
                    Target DeployOutputFiles:
                            Copying file from '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/obj/x86/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.exe' to '/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/bin/Release/AudioCuesheetEditor.exe'
            Done building project "/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.csproj".
            The project 'Packages' is disabled for solution configuration 'Release|x86'.
Done building project "/home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-src-v0.2.1/AudioCuesheetEditor.sln".

Build succeeded.
     0 Warning(s)
     0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.8477090
```

So, can anybody tell me, why the build in rpmbuild fails? Thanks in advance.

Greetings
Sven

Comment: If possible, in your rpmbuild step ask xbuild to generate more information about the failure by setting /v:diag switch. Once you know what is the error and culprit, you can resolve it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find out myself by using this code

```
LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8 xbuild /property:Configuration=Release AudioCuesheetEditor.sln
```

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean? Your comment is a bit unclear to me ;).

Comment: asking "can you elaborate?" is asking exactly what you just said: what do you mean? why LC_CTYPE=xx_XY.UTF-8 works???

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the mono build environment but you should always remember that the rpmbuild environment is not comparable to a "normal" user environment. Mostly **environment variables** are different but also other stuff like resource configs like /home/user/.anyconfigfile.

If you set up the mono build environment while rpmbuilding like your environment and the problem does still exist then you should use strace/ltrace for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I already thought something like the environments is the problem. But how do I configure xbuild? Or should I try to configure gmcs?

Comment: I could find out myself by using this code       LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8 xbuild /property:Configuration=Release AudioCuesheetEditor.sln